# Can I replace a module's exports in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to globally hijack the methods of a module? Or the entire module?

If I have ModuleA that interacts with an external service, and it's used throughout the application. However, when we do our Integration tests (selenium) we want to just intercept these calls and returned canned responses.

Nock.js accomplishes this for http and https calls, however we are using *ldap* protocol for this external service, so we cannot use it.

I would like to just hijack a few methods in this module globally (meaning that no matter where they get called from I can intercept those calls.

Comment: You can't hijack the "first-level" module but you could hijack its attributes. Ex: If a module do `var MyDep = require('asdasd')` and then uses `MyDep.myStaticFunction`, you could do `var MyDep = require('asdasd'); myDep.myStaticFunction = ....` to hijack it. You can also hijack it's prototype if it's a function. However, you won't be able to hijack the constructor itself.

Comment: have you taken a look at proxyquire? it basically allows you to require modules with replaced dependencies